# Socket sends old data

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, subprocess

this is my server:

```
                    s.connect((ip, int(port)))
                    while True:
                        command = input("enter command>")
                        s.send(command.encode())
                        output = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
                        print(output)
                    s.close()
```

client:

```
while 1==1:
    s.listen(5)
    client_socket, client_address = s.accept()
    while True:
        results = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
        if results.lower() == "escape":
            break
        output = subprocess.getoutput(results)
        client_socket.send(output.encode())
    client_socket.close()
    s.close()
```

What is wrong: I sent command 'dir' from server to client, it sucessfuly executed and sent the result back to the server, but after executing different command, the sent output was still the 'dir' output.
Shortly, it is sending still the output of the first command...

Comment: Could you please post the output snapshots.
Ideally,the socket doesn't understand the end of input and hence we need to implement some mechanism to stop reading for input.
I suspect the output to be bigger than the buffer and hence is printing second time.
Please post the output to understand the exact behavior.
Recommend reading the post https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/sockets.html as well.

Comment: Yes, youre right, when I try it with shorter commands like 'whoami' or 'help' it works perfectly, what buffer size do you recommend me? Current is 1024.

Comment: The buffer size depends on the use case of the application.The important part is to implement a mechanisme to read the input with end of the input concept.The article has couple of recommendation like a fixed length input or a end of input word etc.. A buffer size of 2048 is good enough for simple purposes however.

Comment: I tried 4K, but it was not enough for the 'dir' command, I'll end up on 16K for every case.